# Does Matsumura prove that finitely a generated algebra over a field is catenary?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

In *Commutative ring theory*, Matsumura states on page 30

> Practically all the important Noetherian rings arising in applications are known to be catenary;

I think one of the important rings arising in algebraic geometry are finitely generated algebras (and localizations of those) over a field. However I didn't find a proof in Matsumura, that those are actually catenary.

I know that Eisenbud proves this in *Commutative algebra with a view toward algebraic geometry*, so I'm not looking for a reference, just curious if I missed this in Matsumura's book, or if this is really left out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is proven, but without drawing too much attention to it.

> **Theorem 17.9**: Any quotient of a Cohen-Macaulay ring is universally catenary.

This appears in my copy on page 137. As a field is Cohen-Macaulay, the result follows.

Alternatively:

> **Theorem 31.7**: For a noetherian local ring $A$, the following are equivalent:
>
> - $A$ is formally catenary
> - $A$ is universally catenary
> - $A[x]$ is catenary.

(Page 252 in my copy.) So it remains to show that $k[x]$ for a field $k$ is catenary. This is trivial as $k[x]$ is a PID.